# Does Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON handle "black and white icon" properly?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap, gdi+

As stated in [MSDN ICONINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648052(v=vs.85).aspx), depending on whether the structure defines a black and white icon, the `hbmMask` and `hbmColor` are formatted differently.

> **hbmMask**
>
> Type: HBITMAP
>
> The icon bitmask bitmap. If this structure
>   defines a **black and white** icon, this bitmask is formatted so that the
>   upper half is the icon AND bitmask and the lower half is the icon XOR
>   bitmask. Under this condition, **the height should be an even multiple
>   of two**. If this structure defines a color icon, this mask only defines
>   the AND bitmask of the icon.

This means we need to detect the existences of `hbmColor` to properly calculate the icon's height.

However, I later notice `Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON()`, which accepts a `HICON` and converts it to a `Gdiplus::Bitmap`.

Since I don't see any material mentioning about the "black and white" icon in GDI+, does this method has taken care of this situation internally?

(Unfortunately, I don't have a handy icon for testing. I'm not sure how to create a proper test case either.)

Comment: If there isn't any exception mentioned I would assume that `Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON()` handles all possible icon formats. For testing, you can create a black and white icon using the Visual Studio resource editor.

Comment: `ICONINFO` is just a struct that describes an icon.  `HICON` is a handle to an allocated icon in memory that has already setup its pixel data as needed. `FromHICON()` is likely just calling [`GetIconInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648070.aspx) to get an `ICONINFO` from an `HICON` and then copy the bitmap pixels accordingly.